# popular tabela a partir de um combo - jquery / json

Tags: jquery, combobox

Boa tarde! Preciso popular uma tabela a partir do onchange de um combo, via jquery. O problema é que não estou conseguindo manipular o objeto JSON que o PHP me retorna. Alguém tem alguma dica ?

```js
$("#cbCamareiras").on("change",function(){
    var idUserCamareira = $("#cbCamareiras").val();                                           
    $body = $("body");
    $body.addClass("loading");
    $.ajax({
        url:'<?php echo url_for("quartos_sujos_com_agendamento_por_camareira") ?>',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {idCamareira:idUserCamareira},
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function(){},
        success: function (data)
        {  
            $("#dvQuartosSujosComAgendamento").css({'display':'block'}); 
            $("#dvQuartosSujosComAgendamento").html(data);   
        }   
    }) 
});
```

```html
<div class="one column row" id="dvQuartosSujosComAgendamento" style="display:none">
    <table id="tbQuartosSujosAgendados" class="ui celled table">
        <tr style="background-color: #D9D9D9;">
            <td><center><b>Exclusão individual</b></center></td> 
            <td><center><b>Quarto</b></center></td>                                                                      
            <td><center><b>Solicitado por: </b></center></td>
            <td><center><b>Solicitado em: </b></center></td>
            <td><center><b>Limpo ? </b></center></td>
            <td><center><b>Exclusão em massa </b></center></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Retorno JSON do PHP:

```
$idCamareira = $request->getParameter("idCamareira");  
$quartosPorCamareira = QuartoLimpezaPeer::recuperarQuartosSujosAgendadosNovoModuloPorCamareira($idCamareira);           
echo json_encode(array( "objeto" => $quartosPorCamareira));           
die();
```

Comment: esqueci de mencionar o código PHP:  $idCamareira = $request->getParameter("idCamareira");  
            $quartosPorCamareira = QuartoLimpezaPeer::recuperarQuartosSujosAgendadosNovoModuloPorCamareira($idCamareira);           
            echo json_encode(array( "objeto" => $quartosPorCamareira));           
           die();

Comment: Teria como facilitar o entendimento do problema colocando na pergunta um exemplo do json retornado pelo seu php?

Comment: Bart  $idCamareira = $request->getParameter("idCamareira");  
            $quartosPorCamareira = QuartoLimpezaPeer::recuperarQuartosSujosAgendadosNovoModuloPorCamareira($idCamareira);           
            echo json_encode(array( "objeto" => $quartosPorCamareira));           
           die();